# Write a Dockerfile for php-8 apache that runs wordpress and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I want to integrate Wordpress with Laravel. I am building a Dockerfile FROM php:8.0-apache as below:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    --no-install-recommends \
    && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql -j$(nproc) gd \
    && apt-get autoclean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

# Update apache conf to point to application public directory
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

# Update uploads config
RUN echo "file_uploads = On\n" \
         "memory_limit = 1024M\n" \
         "upload_max_filesize = 512M\n" \
         "post_max_size = 512M\n" \
         "max_execution_time = 1200\n" \
         > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini

# Enable headers module
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:

    mycontainer:
        build:
            context: .
        working_dir: /var/www
        image: myimg
        container_name: mycontainer
        ports:
            - 8005:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
```

Here is what I see on http://localhost:8005

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.51 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8005
```

Here is the structure of my files and folders

```
 - laravel   # folder
 - wordpress # folder
 - .htaccess
 - docker-compose.yml
 - Dockerfile
 - index.php
 - .htaccess
```

Comment: This is not really programming related. You could have better luck in other communitues. I found [one possible answer in AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279755/apache-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-this-resource). Or [search on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=apache+You+don%27t+have+permission+to+access+this+resource)?

Answer (score 0):

Might be ownership issue on the www folder.
Try adding this to your dockerfile

```
RUN chown www-data:www-data /var/www/
```